# Building horizontal submenu android

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-menu

I`m trying make a horizontal menu in the drawer navigation android ...but i'm not getting.

Someone already built a menu drawer navigation with horizontal sub menu?
Look the image example:

[image: image]]

Comment: I am trying to understand what it is.. isn't it buttons on the actions menu?

Comment: Hi David. 
They are buttons. The first button shows 3 buttons after click.
The project use the SlidingMenu (jeremyfeinstein library)